# Why R's error handling functions not working in shinyApp?

Tags: r, error-handling, shiny, datatable

To reproduce :

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)

testdf<-c("car1",sample(1:1000,1),sample(1:10,1),sample(1:10,1),sample(1:10,1))
testdf<-rbind(testdf,c("car2",sample(1:1000,1),sample(1:10,1),sample(1:10,1),sample(1:10,1)))
testdf<-data.frame(testdf)

shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(
    tabPanel("tab1",dataTableOutput("datatable")),
    actionButton("CheckFile", "Refresh data")
  ), 
  server = function(input, output, session) {
    X = testdf
    output$datatable = renderDataTable(
      {X},selection = list(mode = 'single',target = 'cell')
    )
    observeEvent(input$CheckFile, {
      tryCatch(eval(testdf[nrow(testdf)+1,]<-c(sample(row.names(mtcars),1),sample(1:1000,1),sample(1:10,1),sample(1:10,1),sample(1:10,1))))
      #same with evaluate function
      #evaluate(testdf[nrow(testdf)+1,]<-c(sample(row.names(mtcars),1),sample(1:1000,1),sample(1:10,1),sample(1:10,1),sample(1:10,1)))
      removeModal()
      showModal(modalDialog(
        title="Refresh done",
        footer=NULL,
        easyClose=T
      ))
    })
  }
)
```

My app is rendering a table. I want to give the user the possibility to update this dataset with an `actionButton()`. It then calls an other R file that update this dataset with `source()`. However, this script may contain some errors and stops before the end. So I chose to handle errors with `tryCatch()` and `eval()`. The problem is that these two functions inside my shiny app avoid the update of the dataset.

I made this reproducible example to illustrate the problem.

When I'm only running this line the dataset is updated:

```
tryCatch(eval(testdf[nrow(testdf)+1,]<-c(sample(row.names(mtcars),1),sample(1:1000,1),sample(1:10,1),sample(1:10,1),sample(1:10,1))))
```

But in the app, it is not the case.

Any idea?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: your example does not run: Warning: Error in renderDataTable: unused argument (selection = list(mode = "single", target = "cell"))

Comment: I forgot to specify that you have to use these two libraries : shiny and DT